# Keeping dependent models representing time in sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm building a angular module, where the user can enter work times. These are the models I need (I'm using momentjs to handle formatting):

- start datetime
- end datetime
- intermission start datetime
- intermission end datetime

The form has these fields:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="start_date"> <!-- Date of work entry YYYY.MM.DD-->
<input type="text" ng-model="start_time"> <!-- Start time of work entry HH:mm -->
<input type="text" ng-model="end_time"> <!-- End time of work entry HH:mm -->
<input type="text" ng-model="intermission_start_time"> <!-- Start time of intermission HH:mm -->
<input type="text" ng-model="intermission_end_time"> <!-- End time of intermission -->
```

I would like to update the models I described above as the user enters the date and I would like to update the input fields as the model update.
This is not trivial, since a work entry may start on the start_date, but may end on the next day (e.g. 20pm - 4am). I'm using momentjs to check if the end time is before the start time and add a day if it is.

Excerpt:

```
if(end_datetime.diff(start_datetime) < 0) {
    end_datetime.add(1, 'd');
}
```

Problem: I can't $scope.$watch the 4 models and update the input models and also $scope.$watch the field models and update the 4 models above, since that would result in an infinite loop.

How can I keep dependent models in sync while performing calculations to get from one to the other?

Comment: I don't completely understand your issue but I suspect that ngChange might be what you need: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange